# Using Komodo IDE as Text editor from the OS X terminal

Tags: macos, komodo-ide

According to [this URL](http://community.activestate.com/faq/komodo-from-the-command-l) I should be able to start Komodo IDE from the command line when I want to edit a file.

I set up the symbolic link using (on single line)

```
ln -sf "/Applications/Komodo IDE.app/Contents/MacOS/komodo" 
        /Users/lexu/bin/komodo
```

but when I type

```
afg-2:~ lexu$ komodo .bash_profile
```

I get

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib   Referenced
>   from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   Reason: Incompatible library version:
>   Security requires version 9.0.0 or
>   later, but libsqlite3.dylib provides
>   version 1.0.0 /Applications/Komodo
>   IDE.app/Contents/MacOS/run-mozilla.sh:
>   line 131:  4370 Trace/BPT trap
>   "$prog" ${1+"$@"}

and a dialog that says:

[image: komodo-bin cannot be opened because of a problem]

My guess is I need to somehow let Komodo know it needs to use different libraries?

Does someone have this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `alias ki='/Applications/Komodo\ IDE.app/Contents/MacOS/komodo-bin'` to your ~/.bashrc

Then just do `$ ki somefile`

EDIT:  Changed it, didn't realize you were using Komodo IDE

Comment: I'd tried that before, but got a different error that lead me to believe starting the '-bin' was a nono! (I'll add that as an Edit to the Question though!)

Comment: OOPS: I just realized you are going the alias route .. that worked! Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you call the program directly from it's regular location?  If so, then very likely there is a dependency on where the program is located.  To get around that you could, instead of having a symbolic link in ~/bin/komodo, make that file a small script such as:

```
exec /Applications/Komodo IDE.app/Contents/MacOS/komodo
```

Change the permissions of that file with "chmod 755 ~/bin/komodo".  Then it should work (assuming the problem was that it worked OK from its original location).

You could also adjust your PATH variable to include /Applications/Komodo IDE.app/Contents/MacOS .  Then there would be no need to have a symbolic link or script in your ~/bin .

Comment: Nope, didn't work, I get the same error when using exec

Comment: `exec /Applications/Komodo\ IDE.app/Contents/MacOS/komodo-bin` did work however! Thanks for teaching me about exec!

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is have ~/bin/komodo.sh which has

```
#!/bin/sh
/Applications/Komodo\ IDE.app/Contents/MacOS/komodo-bin "$@"
```

I then have ~/bin as part of my path

I can then do

```
$komodo index.php
```

and it loads. However because I like to be even quicker, I have a shell alias which is:

```
alias kom="komodo"
```

so that I can do:

```
$kom index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

the exec solution kind of worked for me but when closing the Komodo window/app it closed my iTerm (with all of it's tabs :-(

For an OSX'ian approach:

> open /Applications/Komodo\ Edit.app

If you associated files with komodo you can call open from the command line.  e.g. if you right click on a .py file and click on get-info, say open-with komodo and click on Change-All, you can then from the command line just say:

> open somefile.py

Answer (score -1):

That FAQ is out of date. We'll make sure that gets updated. The best way to start komodo from the command line on OS X is to use 'alias' like so:

```
alias komodo='open -a "Komodo IDE"'
```

...or:

```
alias komodo='open -a "Komodo Edit"'
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, please edit your reply and add a path to the new FAQs, when available.